# How to handle a set of array inputs and insert multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables namely invoice and purchase_list.

INVOICE :

invoice_number,
invoice_date,
customer_id,
invoice_purchase_value,
invoice_tax,
invoice_bill_amount

PURCHASE_LIST

purchase_id,
invoice_number,
customer_id,
purchase_rate,
purchase_quantity,
purchase_value

For a particular bill, i insert the bill's main details in invoice table and its corresponding products purchase list in purchase_list table.

Usually many products been purchased in one invoice.

Here comes the problem. One insert statement is enough for invoice table.
But, for purchase_list, multiple insert statements required.
(For ex, If 6 items purchased in one invoice, 6 insert statements should be executed.)

I am in thought of sending all purchased values in array format from PHP. If so, how can i extract values from those arrays and insert it into purchase_list table or any other ways to implement the same..?

I am newbie to MySql. Please brief in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What You have tried yet ? show me some code you tried ...

Comment: For example, if 6 purchased items are there for a particular invoice, i am calling the insert statement for purchase_list, 6 times from php using loop. Instead, i want to send the purchase items values in an array and if i can handle those array values in routine, to insert from backend.

Answer (score 0):

look into PDO prepared statements.